# error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)

Tags: c++, c, binutils

I am trying to build an old binutils (2.13). getting the error ./config/obj-elf.c:364: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)  on the next line :

```
if (symbol_get_obj (symbolP)->local)
{...
```

the function symbol_get_obj :

```
OBJ_SYMFIELD_TYPE *
symbol_get_obj (s)
     symbolS *s;
{
  if (LOCAL_SYMBOL_CHECK (s))
    s = local_symbol_convert ((struct local_symbol *) s);
  return &s->sy_obj;
}
```

OBJ_SYMFIELD_TYPE is defined to be :

```
#define OBJ_SYMFIELD_TYPE struct elf_obj_sy
```

and elf_obj_sy is

```
struct elf_obj_sy
{
  /* Whether the symbol has been marked as local.  */
  int local;

  /* Use this to keep track of .size expressions that involve
     differences that we can't compute yet.  */
  expressionS *size;

  /* The name specified by the .symver directive.  */
  char *versioned_name;

#ifdef ECOFF_DEBUGGING
  /* If we are generating ECOFF debugging information, we need some
     additional fields for each symbol.  */
  struct efdr *ecoff_file;
  struct localsym *ecoff_symbol;
  valueT ecoff_extern_size;
#endif
};
```

couldn't understand what is wrong with this code ... any advice ?

Comment: Could you show where are you getting the error?

Comment: on the if line : if (symbol_get_obj (symbolP)->local)

Comment: Probably your `symbol_get_obj` is undefined, the compiler make it a default `int` return type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error message, one possible reason is that the declaration of the function `symbol_get_obj` fails to appear **before** the place you call it, which makes the return value default to type `int`, an invalid type for operator `->`.  You might want to check this.  Make sure the correct presence of `symbol_get_obj`'s declaration through header file inclusion or explicit function prototype.

Comment: I might have guessed it if I have looked at the compiler warnings 1 line before this error : warning: implicit declaration of function ‘symbol_get_obj’ ... thx.

Answer (score 2):

```
invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
```

That can only make sense if

```
symbol_get_obj(symbolP)
```

returns `int`. Which it does not.

So, the only logical conclusion is that `symbol_get_obj` has not been declared at the point in the code where the error occurs. In which case the compiler will assume that it is a function that returns a value of type `int`. Which would then explain the error message.